# name "property" to any random name in a object shape

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript, just a question on the syntax, I saw some code like define a passing parameter like this:

```
{ [property: string]: any}
```

I'm a little bit confused here, I get the point that this parameter has to a object and its property has to be string. But I can actually name "property" to any random name like:

```
{ [SomeNonSenseName: string]: any}
```

and it still works exactly the same way as it was before, so the property name doesn't actually matter and we are not going to refer to this property name, is it a weak design of typescript?

Comment: Are you using the above object anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `{ [property: string]: any}` defines an [Indexable Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

> we can also describe types that we can “index into” like a[10], or ageMap["daniel"]. Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing.
>
> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number.

In your case, it means that you have an Object which can have a set of properties, and each property is of `any` type.

The `property` word you used is part of the indexer signature, not the name of expected property.

```
let user: { [property: string]: any}  = { name: 'John', age: 30};
console.log(user['name']) 
console.log(user['age']) 
user['city'] = 'NY'
console.log(user['city'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> so the property name doesn't actually matter and we are not going to refer to this property name

Correct, however it does enforce that indexed property keys are of type string. You can explicitly define additional properties too

One thing worth noting is that this name can be useful for documentation purposes, for example if you had a dictionary of arguments to values, you might do `{ [argName: string]: string }`